# Jquery delete spring bound row: still on request?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm using spring-web-flow + spring mvc.
Within my spring web flow when a validation error occurs I go back to the page on which it occurred as is the default in spring web flow.

The issue I'm having is that on the page on which the error occurs a user can add/remove rows in which there are input fields which are bound. (just using some javascript to add `fieldname[X]`). When I submit the added fields are correctly bound, however when I land back on the page due to a validation error, remove the row using jquery `remove()` and then submit again the removed row(s) are still on the request object?